# how to get input value with ajax and show it in php

Tags: php, ajax

here is my input

```
<textarea id="mytext" class="txtarea" name="in_content" cols="120" rows="15"><?php echo $term;?></textarea>
```

here is my ajax code that take value of the textarea above

```
$('#spdf-form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#spdf_results').html(data);
            $('#spdf-form').fadeOut('slow');
            var textAreaValue = $("#mytext").text();
            alert(textAreaValue);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

it's works, and show the value in the alert popup. Now i want to show the result as php code. i want to insert the value into tinymce editor, and the editor will be called like this

```
<?php the_editor(''); ?>
```

so i think i should do this

```
$myvalues = something to get the results from ajax function
```

and then i call the editor like this

```
<?php the_editor($myvalues); ?>
```

but i dont know how to do that, can someone help me please? i tried to get the value directly but it didnt work also.

Comment: That is because the PHP script runs on the server side, and your AJAX runs on the client side.

The editor should have an API for that, you'll have to do some digging yourself.

Comment: Couldn't you make another ajax-call to theeditor.php inside the success: function() to the file and send textAreaValue's value to theeditor.php ?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side. JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX is client-side. You can't run PHP on the same page after it's been sent to the client.

You'll need to use AJAX to request your editor code from the server, then take the editor code and insert it into the page.